# Testing React DOM with Jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to make this tests with Jest, but i did not find how to implementate tests for document.querySelect() functions, Thats how far i could go with it:

```
describe("Ui manipulation and scans", () =>{
  render(
    <Provider store={Store}>
      <InputData />
    </Provider>
  
  )


  it("get all inputs",() => {
    expect(getAllInputs()).toHaveLength(5);
  })
  it("search warning",() => {
    const arr = getAllInputs()
    expect(searchWarning(arr)).toBe(false);
  })

})
```

and here the getAllInputs function:

```
export function getAllInputs () {
  const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
  var arr = [];
  for(var i = inputs.length; i--; arr.unshift(inputs[i]));
  return arr

}
```

Comment: react-testing-library provides you with ready queries, check out the docs https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-queries#queries

Comment: I did read about the queries and saw a bunch of examples, but my function is suppose to do the query work, i don't know how to set the function as it was called inside the component.

Answer (score 0):

I founded out I was using the wrong scope.
by simple changing the render function inside the it scope the test worked.

```
describe("Ui manipulation and scans", () =>{

  it("get all inputs",() => {
    render(
      <Provider store={Store}>
        <InputData />
      </Provider>
    )

    expect(getAllInputs()).toHaveLength(5);
  })
  it("search warning",() => {
    const {getAllByRole} = render(
      <Provider store={Store}>
        <InputData />
      </Provider>
    )
    
    expect(searchWarning(getAllByRole("textbox"))).toBe(false);
  })
```